# Selenium and ChromeDriver occasionally returning wrong content for GET requests

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

A console app in C# that requests four images in a tight loop sometimes returns a previous request. The code is as below and works against any web site, I typically see 3 or 4 errors per run. I developed this code after reports from people browsing a web site I manage where occasionally a jpeg or script would be loaded when the user requested a HTML page.

I don't know if it is a Chrome or ChromeDriver issue. If the previous request was an HTML page then you can end up with getting that instead of the image. Seems to be a race condition.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour and can they repeat it with the code below?

```
class ContentVerify
{
    OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver driver;

    readonly System.Collections.Generic.List<string> testUrls = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>()
    {
        "http://i.imgur.com/zNJvS.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/lzVec.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/rDuhT.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/sZ26q.jpg"
    };

    public void Check()
    {
        driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(); // Both InternetExplorerDriver and FirefoxDriver work OK.

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TestUrls();
        }
        driver.Quit(); // The driver also crashes on exit, but this seems to be a known bug in Selenium.
    }

    private void TestUrls()
    {
        foreach (var item in testUrls)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item);
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1); // Uncommenting this makes Chrome & ChromeDriver work as expected.
            driver.Url = item;
            // Requests for images come back as an HTML image tag wrapped in a brief HTML page, like below;
            //<html><body style="margin: 0px;"><img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://i.imgur.com/zNJvS.jpg"></body></html>
            // So the image should always be in the page, but sometimes (not always) we get the previous image requested.
            if (!driver.PageSource.Contains(item))
            {
                System.Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Red;
                System.Console.WriteLine("Expected: {0}, got: {1}", item, driver.PageSource);
                System.Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you're not giving the driver enough time to complete the call and have the page load, so it'll "return" whatever previous page it had returned. Have you looked into setting up a [timeout/wait](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html) on the driver?

**EDIT**

With regards to the question of *why* there is this issue in Chrome but not the other browsers, I'd had to venture a guess and say that it probably has to do with how the different browser engines handle displaying an image directly instead of HTML. I make this assumption due to the fact that this discrepancy as described is not seen when running similar code against an HTML page like the Google home page.

Each browser wraps the image in some HTML. For example, IE9 wraps as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY><IMG src="[url here]"></BODY></HTML>
```

Whereas Firefox wraps it like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width; height=device-height;" name="viewport">
    <link href="resource://gre/res/TopLevelImageDocument.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>[filename] (JPEG Image, 500&nbsp;×&nbsp;332 pixels)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img alt="[url here]" src="[url here]">
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, Chrome:

```
<html>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
    <img style="-webkit-user-select: none; " src="[url here]" width="500" height="332">
</body>
<style type="text/css"></style>
</html>
```

Now, I don't know why the Chrome version causes the webdriver to be unable to detect the pageload. It certainly is the most minimal of the three HTML wrappers, and the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) has a mild panic attack when asked to validate its HTML while the other two validate relatively well.

Also, as mentioned by mootinator, there have been numerous complaints about the Chrome driver in general so it could be just an issue with the Chrome webdriver itself. I just found the above interesting and thought it might be worthwhile to share.

Comment: Yes, it could be. I would hope that the ChromeDriver worked the same way as the Firefox and IE ones though and they don't require that delay, they block until the content has loaded.

Comment: Well adding the delay to the other drivers shouldn't actually hurt processing, just maybe make it take longer. And if it's an implicit wait instead of explicit (eg. wait until element is present instead of wait 30 seconds) then it might not increase processing time at all.

Comment: I'd like to find the reason for it though, is it a bug in ChromeDriver or Chrome? The reason I want to find out is that in Chrome when browsing live sites the occasional GET request goes missing and this test case seems to reproduce that.

Comment: I don't know, personally. If I had to guess, I'd say it might be a browser engine issue instead of a browser issue. A test case might be to see if the same thing happens on other webkit browsers like Safari.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a lot of complaints about performance with the Chrome driver.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1294

Two facts:
1. Chrome itself is not a poorly performing browser.
2. Requests for new URLs are sent asynchronously.

Regardless of what the actual implementation is, it's apparent that the Chrome driver has a performance problem somewhere in the process of making requests and/or updating itself with the results of requests.

The Selenium driver doesn't *guarantee* that a page will be finished loading before you want to take a peek at it.  As such, it can't reasonably be called a bug in the driver if you happen to get a race condition in one of your tests.  In order to make reliable selenium tests you need to rely on using, as Roddy indicated, timeout/wait.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Selenium for sometime now and its always the case where the C# code have finished executing before even the request page was fully loaded, means selenium is very slow in doing its functionality. So in order for selenium to do its stuff we ended using Thread.Sleep and our tests have started working correctly

I agree not the nice way to do it but we have tried various ways and failed to find cleaner solution

Please see link for information [Why is Selenium RC so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354590/why-is-selenium-rc-so-slow) on this same page at the right side their are some related links on other issues related to selenium